# My javaScript just stopped working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I'm trying to create checks so that if someone hasn't entered a zip code, phone number, or email address properly then the javascript will display an alert and the form won't be submitted.  If any of the fields aren't filled (null || =="") then the javascript will also display an alert and wont submit the form.

It was working just fine but then all of the sudden stopped working... I've been looking at it for awhile now and cannot figure out why.

Here's my code (.php):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Adding Companies</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../ResponsiveTopNavDropdown.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="toggleNav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div id="toggleNav"><a href="#" onclick="toggleNav()">Show/Hide Navigation</a></div>

    <nav id="nav">
        <?php include('../nav.html'); ?>
    </nav>


        <h1 id="mainheader">WELCOME TO MISSISSIPPI VALLEY CHAPTER 123</h1>

        <section class="content-wide">
            <?php
                session_start();
                if ($_SESSION['check'] != "true") {
                    header('Location: http://www.mississippivalleyashrae.org/Admin/admin_login.php');
                }
                $_SESSION['my_company'] = null;

            ?>
                <h3><strong>You're currently in the process of: Adding a Company<strong></h3>
                <table width = "760" border = "0" align = "center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor = "#cccccc">
                  <tr>
                    <form onSubmit="return validateCompany()" action="adding_manufacturer.php" method="post">
                    <td>
                      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="3"><strong> Enter the Information for this New Company </strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="3" align = "left">
                            Company Name<br />
                            <input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" placeholder="My Company .Inc"
                                   size="100" maxlength="125"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="3" align = "left">
                            Address<br />
                            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="1234 My Street Ave."
                                   size="100" maxlength="100"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align = "left" width="250">
                            City<br />
                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Rock Island" size="30" maxlength="30"></td>
                          <td align = "left" width="250">
                            State<br />
                            <select name="state">
                                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="CA">California</option>
                                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                            </select></td>
                          <td align = "left" width="250">
                            Zip-Code<br />
                            <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="61201" size="6" maxlength="6"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align = "left" width="250">
                            Phone<br />
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="515-555-0000" size="12" maxlength="12"></td>
                          <td colspan="2" align = "left" width="250">
                            Email Address<br />
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="myemail24@gmail.com"
                                   size="50" maxlength="50"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="3">
                            <br />
                            <input type ="submit" name="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Add This Company"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                    </form>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <p>
                    **Make sure all information is entered correctly!<br />
                    If you enter any information incorrectly you can go back and edit it from the
                    <a href="http://www.mississippivalleyashrae.org/Admin/admin_main.php">Admin Main</a> page!
                </p>
            <script src="formValidators.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </section>
```

And here's my javascript (formValidators.js):

```
function validateCompany() {
    var checkCompanyName = document.getElementById("company_name").value;
    var checkAddress = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var checkCity = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var checkState = document.getElementById("state").value;
    var checkZip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
    var checkPhone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var checkEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;

    // checks for any null fields
    if ((checkCompanyName==null || checkCompanyName=="") || (checkAddress==null || checkAddress=="") ||
    (checkCity==null || checkCity=="") || (checkState==null || checkState=="") ||
    (checkZip==null || checkZip=="")|| (checkPhone==null || checkPhone=="") ||
    (checkEmail==null || checkEmail=="")){
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        return false;
    }
    var zipPattern = /^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$/;
    if (zipPattern.test(checkZip) == false){
        alert("Invalid Zip-Code, Please Re-Enter the zip-code in the correct format");
        return false;
    }
    var phonePattern = /^()?\d{3}()?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/;
    if (phonePattern.test(checkPhone) == false){
        alert("Invalid Phone Number, Please Re-Enter the phone number in the correct format");
        return false;
    }
    var emailPattern = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    if (emailPattern.test(checkEmail) == false){
        alert("Invalid Email, Please Re-Enter the email in the correct format");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: press F12 and click on console. Do you find any errors ?

Comment: So, what was the last change you made?

Comment: Just curious. Why are there empty capturing groups, e.g. `()` within your regular experssions?

Comment: The only error in the console I was finding was something regarding the <script src="toggleNav.js"> stuff but that shouldn't change anything...

Comment: The last change made was adding the zipPattern and the if statement for it.  I then went to go check it (with a zip code that has letters in it) it didn't display an alert box and submitted the form

Comment: Why are you using `\\d` instead of `\d` in the `zipPattern` check?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<form>` as a child of `<tr>`, the children of `<tr>` have to be `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: Can you show the code of the "toggleNav.js" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in your state drop down:

```
<select name="state">
```

There is no ID to get, so your JS is failing, silently I might add.

```
<select name="state" id="state">
```

I modified the selector to include an ID and it's now firing properly.

Comment: that's it! thanks!!
sidenote: I hate dumb errors like that... bane of my existence as a web programmer and programmer in general

Comment: Yeah, it was small and with the "silent" error I just had to do a bit of the ole brute force "add an alert here, here and here" method. Every one's been there and every one will go back.